# Making panorama items headers closer to each other in WP7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, panorama-control

I'm using panorama for the first time in WP7 Silverlight. My problem is that only the half of the first letter of the next panorama item header appears.

I'm afraid the user will not know that there is another part to slide to.

This is a sample for what I need:

http://briansolli.files.wordpress.com/2011/03/leaderboard.png

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need here is not panaroma but pivot page. It works exactly like what is shown in image.Look at this example for guidance -

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stephanc/archive/2010/05/09/windows-phone-7-pivot-control-sample.aspx

Comment: please mark the above as an answer if it solves ur problem. :)